# Given a large number of pdfs, how to merge them quickly into specified groups

Tags: pdf

While there are many tools that can merge pdfs, most of them merge all the pdfs you upload/select at once; however, I have large number of pdfs that I want to merge into groups of 2 to 4, which means I need to select a small number of pdfs, merge those, and then repeat the process.

Is there a quicker way to do this, perhaps a manual tool that allows me to upload all my pdfs, and then drag and drop them onto each other specifying which subsets I want to merge in which order (ideally naming the merged files in terms of the individual file names, so I know what each contains quickly.

Comment: What are you merging them based on? Filename? A file attribute? Metadata? Something text within the file?

Comment: Roughly by filename, but it isn't super systematic; I manually select which ones I want merge together. Though maybe a filename solution could be faster than what I'm thinking of right now.

Comment: You probably want to build your own script for this.

Comment: Unscientific comment solution rather than an answer - use `move` in the command line using the filename pattern to put files to be merged into a sub-directory. Then have a script/batch file which runs based on the contents of the directory alone.